# create a graph using PHP using data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jpgraph

I am a beginner for PHP.
I need to  create a line graph using PHP using data from MySQL

(I had downloaded jpgraph but I do not know how to use it)

Comment: http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto.php

Comment: I would first try to build up a HTML Page, created by PHP and would leave mysql for a later step (reduce complexity). Use some dummy data. Then install this PHP  jpgraph-library and try it with the manual.

Answer (score 3):

jpgraph has an [extensive documentation](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/index.html) for nearly every php skill level.

Included in the download package are many examples on how to use every kind of charts available for you.

Make sure to

- install it properly (read about it [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch03.html)),
- [run the examples](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch02s02.html) (if they don't work, it isn't installed properly).

Then get a grip on how it works while analyzing the examples provided.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you've know some basic of php, html, javascript and mysql.
See the documentation of jpgraph from the official site of jpgraph.
[How To](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto.php)

[what kind of chart](http://jpgraph.net/features/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the littel information you have given in your question i would suggest you start here:

[jpgraph HowTo](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto.php)